# What programming language is used for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone

So basically, I want to know, what programming languages and in what compiler I can make iPhone apps?

Basically, currently my knowledge in programming is -

PHP, HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, Jquery, AJAX, C++, Pascal and a little bit JAVA.

What programming language is used for iPhone apps?

Comment: The very first "Related Tag" on the page of [tag:iphone] questions is [tag:objective-c]. Maybe that's a hint?

Comment: Failing that, in the time it took you to write this Google could've told you the answer.

Comment: See: Objective-C vs PhoneGap [SO question and asswers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026786/objective-c-vs-phonegap).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language is [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C). If you know HTML and JavaScript you can look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

Comment: Well, basically as far as I understood I can make everything same with PhoneGap what I can make with Objective-C, correct?

Answer (score 5):

- the native language is Objective-C, but you can also use C, C++ and JS
- or you can user HTML/CSS + Javascript with the [PhoneGap SDK](http://phonegap.com/)
- or you can user C# with the [Monotouch SDK](http://xamarin.com/monotouch)
- or you can use JS with [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Swift is a multi-paradigm, compiled programming language created by Apple for iOS and OS X development. Introduced at Apple's 2014 Worldwide Developers Conference, Swift is designed to work with Apple's Cocoa and Cocoa Touch frameworks and the large body of existing Objective-C code written for Apple products.

Check below link for more reference:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/

Answer (score 2):

The native iPhone apps is using Objective C. You can also inject C++ and C in it too. But if you are proficient with Javascript, you might want to look at [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) which basically will compile javascript into Objective-C and or [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) which will embed webapps into iPhone apps.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Objective C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)